# Show hidden text on hover (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have tried for a while now to show some text on `:hover`, is anyone able to explain it for me?

I tried:

```
#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenText {
     display: block;}
```

without luck, sadly. This little piece is in every example I found.

I also failed to understand: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/show-text-on-hover-with-css/

I try to get `<div id="DivForHoverItem"><p>Shown text</p></div>`

```
<div id="HiddenText"><p>Hidden text</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#HiddenText {
   display: none;
}
```

and the code line up there ^

```
#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenText {
     display: block;}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and entire relevant CSS.

Comment: Post your HTML, the CSS by itself does not show where the problem is.

Comment: There is no problem what so ever, I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. Nothing in my code is interacting, as my code is a plain test with only that Little Peace.

Comment: Well show us your code where you tried to do this, and we can help you find what's wrong. If we can't see what you've done, we can't help you figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The #HiddenText element has to be inside the #DivForHoverItem element if you want to achieve this with CSS. Try something like this:

```css
#DivForHoverItem {
    /*just so we can see it*/
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

#HiddenText {
    display: none;
}

#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenText {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="DivForHoverItem">
  <div id="HiddenText"><p>Hidden text</p></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle link for convenience](http://jsfiddle.net/v3tsx9pd/)

Comment: Thank you, Works - good demonstration, really understand it now :)

Comment: All he had to do was change `#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenText` to `#DivForHoverItem:hover + #HiddenText` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: It wasn't clear how his entire DOM was laid out; I didn't know that they were definitely sequential elements. Good point though, that's definitely a good way to achieve this.

Comment: I can't seem to add Transition: all 1s; to this... any clue why?

Comment: @iversen display is a property that can't be animated. if you want to have a fade-in effect, you should have the opacity of the element go from 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

If you're okay with using JavaScript you could use:

```
var outDiv = document.getElementById('DivForHoverItem');
var inDiv = document.getElementById('HiddenText');

outDiv.onmouseover = function() {
     inDiv.style.display = 'inline';
};

outDiv.onmouseout = function() {
     inDiv.style.display = 'none';
};
```