# How do I use an Inspector to find the HTML in a theme's PHP files?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website for someone and I have a question. I used an inspector (firebug) to check out the html of my site but I need to know where to find that bit of code in the Wordpress theme (Spacing) php files. There's no search all feature and going through all of them separately is ridiculous.

I really appreciate any help you can offer!!

I found an article on it (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/search-through-php-files) but there really wasn't a solution. If I can find what I'm looking for in the HTML (it's a menu name by the way), why can't I go find it in the theme files??

I don't know if this matters but the HTML is a body class to a couple of div classes to a ul id to li id to an a class.

Comment: If you want to change the menu name you can do so , visit back-end->appearance->menus and change the name of menus. Or else pls elaborate what specifically you want to be changed

Answer (score 1):

WP does not contain ant HTML page. Everything in WordPress php file. If your page is created in page section you have to check in page.php file in  /wp-content/themes/{your theme name}/page.php or if your page is posts you to check in post.php

What you want to change in WordPress site ?

Comment: I'm trying to make text show up on hover after a menu item. Problem is that I can't figure out where that menu div is located in order to add the hidden text div after it (as shown in this article here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549280/show-hidden-text-on-hover-css)

Comment: you can use custom css or write jQuery for hover effect.

Comment: Well yes but I need to write the text into the html first, which is my problem

Comment: Fetch id from html element where you want to put your html. Then near to that HTML tag insert your html using jQuery and on hover apply a custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the back-end/admin section and click "Pages". Find the page you are working on and click edit. In the "Page Attributes" you can see what "Template" it is using.

Then you can find that template in /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/

EDIT: More than likely the header and navigation is located in the "header.php" file in the themes folder.