# Show Hidden webbot in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've tried using the scenario in the link below too show hidden text when mouse over text. It works fine with text but what my client is needing is to hide the webbot HitCounter and show it when they place the mouse over. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Show hidden text on hover (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549280/show-hidden-text-on-hover-css)

```
<div id="DivForHoverItem">
            <div id="HiddenText"><p class="auto-style4">
                <!--webbot bot="HitCounter" i-image="0" I-ResetValue="0" I-Digits="0" U-Custom --></p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
/* Div for hover item */
#DivForHoverItem {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align:center;
}

#HiddenText {
    display:none;
}

#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenText {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. If you know how to hide text (or content) by means of css, then you can also do that for whatever content that div holds. So _what is the actual question here_?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you actually want?

Comment: What my client actually needs if for the counter to be invisible then when the mouse is over the "webbot", show the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `display:none` "removes" element (div do not occupy space) from layout. So You have nothing to point with cursor (without creating another wrapping div/divs with fixed size, or gettinng into js and conditions of another element) to start the hover effect.

So maybe outer wrapper div?
Maybe `visibility: hidden` in place `display:none`?
Maybe Changing the `Z-Index`?
Or another div on top of counter (covering it with background solid color) with alpha transparency change on hover (even fading out css animation) ?

Comment: I tried replacing with visibility: hidden, still no changes in the outcome. Can you give me an example of Changing the Z-Index?

Comment: hidden could be done with z-index: -99, and show with z-index: 99